# How to get report of gem 'rqrcode-with-patches', '~> 0.5.4'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, qr-code

I am using gem 'rqrcode-with-patches', '~> 0.5.4' gem for generating QR Code. I would like to know how to get information of the device which scanned my QR Code along with the location of users who are scanning my QR Code.

Answer (score 0):

Shorten the URL that you want to encode so the user is redirected from an analytics service to the final URL. I wouldn't recommend that practice.

Comment: I want to generate report of device who scanned my qr code. How this work when the url is shorten

Comment: Your qrcode targets a specific URL. Let's name it A. But you want to know more about every clients that access A with the qrcode. So you go on a URL shortening service and based on A, it will generate B, which is a link that redirects everybody to A after fetching some information from the client. Instead of generating a qrcode for A, you generate one for B.

Comment: @ruby forgot to tag